# Database Schema nestest Tasklist

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design, eloquent, rdbms

I am working on a database for an ordered tasklist. As some of the tasks are repetitive I need a "taskList" that can again consist of tasks and other task lists.

[Find example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WVVw.png)

In the above example TaskList 1 consists of [TaskList2, Task5, Task 6, TaskList3], where TaskList2 consists of [Task1, Task2, Task3, Task4] and so on.

My main question is:
What's the best way to set up a Database-Schema to handle this nested polymorphism? (I am using Laravels ORM)

Comment: Define 'best'!!

Comment: I'm not sure it applies to this case, but you might want to research "Nested Sets".  It's a way of representing a hierarchy of objects in a way that's easy to manipulate (although hard to maintain). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, your problem is solved by considering a tasklist as an ordered aggregation of tasklist items, which are tasks or (other) tasklists, as described by the following class diagram:

[image]

A DB schema that implements this conceptual model is provided by the following table schemas (where PK/FK = primary/foreign keys, and ? = optional):

```
tasklists( PK id, name)
tasks( PK id, name)
tasklistitems( 
    FK tasklist REF tasklists, 
    seq_no, 
    FK taskitem? REF tasks, 
    FK tasklistitem? REF tasklists
)
```

such that each row of `tasklistitems` is related to a tasklist via its first (foreign key) attribute and references either a task or a tasklist via the corresponding optional foreign key attributes `taskitem` and `tasklistitem`.

Notice that the sequence number attribute of tasklist items implements their ordering.

Comment: why are you using FK tasklist_id, and  FK tasklist_id?

Comment: This was a naming mistake, which I've corrected. The first `tasklist_id` FK attribute was supposed to relate the item to the tasklist, while the second one is optional and references another tasklist as an item. Notice that I've improved my answer, now with a class diagram.

Comment: @Simon Bigelmayr: I've added REFERENCES clauses to the foreign keys in the schema of `tasklistitems`.